# How can binary names in command prompt be colored

Tags: ls, colors

I recently saw in a presentation that the typed in commands that matched something in /bin /sbin /... were colored green.

It looked nice and felt more structured. How can this be achieved with standard bash?

Comment: For zsh, [the zsh-syntax-highlighting plugin](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting) does this. Apparently, the feature's inspired by the fish shell.

Comment: Short answer: doesn't look like it can be done in bash. See http://superuser.com/a/868720/334516